# How to mock an API that returns a JSON string in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking

I am a beginner in trying to mock an external API in [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot).

Here is the API:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

It returns a JSON string like this:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
...
```

I've tried the following code:

```
    @Service
    public class BlogPostService {
        @Autowired
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;

        public String getAllBlogPosts() {
            ResponseEntity resp = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/posts", String.class);

            return resp.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK ? resp.getBody() : null;
        }

    }
```

But there is an error in the IDE at resp.getBody() which says:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String

Here is my *BlogPost* code:

```
public class BlogPost {
    private int userId;
    private String title;
    private String body;

    public BlogPost() {
    }

    public BlogPost(int userId, String title, String body) {
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }
//...getters & setters
```

How can I fix this?  Hopefully without the use of yet another tool.  This is just a simple proof-of-concept application, so I do not want to use [JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) or [Mockito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockito) for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` returns an array of JSON objects. You will need to reflect this in your request's desired response type:

```java
public String getAllBlogPosts() {
    ResponseEntity resp = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/posts", BlogPost[].class);

    return resp.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK ? resp.getBody() : null;
}
```

Notice the `[]` in `BlogPost[].class`.

Then, you are getting a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String` since `ResponseBody.getBody()` returns a generic type `T`, which is `BlogPost[]`, but your method signature returns a `String`.

If all you want is the JSON string, then you can just do this:

```java
public String getAllBlogPosts() {
    ResponseEntity resp = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/posts", String.class);

    return resp.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK ? resp.getBody() : null;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want the actual [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) array then do this:

```java
public BlogPost[] getAllBlogPosts() {
    ResponseEntity resp = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/posts", BlogPost[].class);

    return resp.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK ? resp.getBody() : null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that silly error out.  Its good to know I am getting close.  I made the change to String.class and updated my post with that.  Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I got it fixed by changing the line to: ResponseEntity<String> resp = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/posts", String.class);